# DocuSign API JAVA - How to fill programmatically the fields company and title for each signer

Tags: docusignapi

There is a programmatically way for filling the fields **Company** and **Title** for each signer? How?

In this sample code, the document from template is replaced by other defined as a parameter of the method:

```
public ESenderSummary sendDocumentsToSignByOrderOfSigner(List<ESigner> eSigners, String templateId, List<EDocument> eDocuments) throws ESignException {
            String docuSignAccountId = docuSignAuthenticationProvider.getAccountId();
    
            TemplatesApi templatesApi = docuSignAuthenticationProvider.getTemplatesApi();
            List<TemplateRole> templateRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    
            String emailSubject;
            EmailSettings emailSettings;
            Recipients recipients;
            try {
                EnvelopeTemplate envelopeTemplate = templatesApi.get(docuSignAccountId, templateId);
                emailSubject = envelopeTemplate.getEmailSubject();
                recipients = envelopeTemplate.getRecipients();
                List<Signer> signers = recipients.getSigners();
    
                int index = 1;
                for (Signer signer : signers) {
                    ESigner eSigner = eSigners.get(index - 1);
                    // create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
                    signer.setEmail(eSigner.getEmail());
                    signer.setName(eSigner.getFirstName() + " " + eSigner.getLastName());
    
                    // create a templateRole for each signer from recipient to sign the document
                    TemplateRole templateRole = new TemplateRole();
                    templateRole.setEmail(eSigner.getEmail());
                    templateRole.setName(eSigner.getFirstName() + " " + eSigner.getLastName());
                    templateRole.setRoleName("signer" + index);
                    templateRole.setRoutingOrder(String.valueOf(index)); // ordering of sign
                    templateRoles.add(templateRole);
    
                    index++;
                }
    
                recipients.setSigners(signers);
                emailSettings = envelopeTemplate.getEmailSettings();
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                throw new ESignException("DocuSign API failed to retrieve envelope template " + templateId + ": " +  e.getMessage());
            }

        // Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject(emailSubject);
        envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);
        envelopeDefinition.setEmailSettings(emailSettings);
        envelopeDefinition.setTemplateRoles(templateRoles);
        envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(createDocuments(eDocuments));

        return sendEnvelope(envelopeDefinition, docuSignAccountId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done if the signers are DocuSign users in the account and then you update their account/user information with their company and title.

Company and Title are fixed tabs, so you could use text tab where you programmatically update the value and make them also read-only. You will achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit! 
But when I try to retrieve the Tabs from Document Template 
`Tabs tabs = templatesApi.getDocumentTabs(docuSignAccountId, templateId, templateDocument.getDocumentId())`  

The all lists of properties of _tabs_ are empty.

I thought the usage of custom fields. But I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: See this - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-custom-field-values is has code examples in 8 langs, including Java